# Login log in SharePoint 2016 with Form Based Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication

I have developed a SharePoint application with custom login page using form based authentication and Active directiory

Now I want to log the failed login attempt in the application as well as who is login in the system.

Plase help.

Answer (score 0):

We can use SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace method to add log to ULS log in custom login page.

In order to make ULS logging work for a AppPool account that is not Administrator, you have to add your AppPool user to "Performance Log Users" group.

Reference:

[How to write custom logs into ULS logs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2010/04/16/how-to-write-custom-logs-into-uls-logs-sharepoint-foundation-2010-wss-4-0/)

[Write to ULS Logs Programmatically](https://bipinpankhania.wordpress.com/2015/06/25/write-to-uls-logs-programmatically-in-sharepoint-2013sharepoint-2010-on-premise/)